# Excel 2010: Counting cells with adjacent cell blank

Tags: excel

I have data in rows where each column represents a day, some of which are blank and some of which have numbers.  I want to "scan" down the row, comparing each cell with the one before to the left of it (or the one 2 spaces left of it, etc).  For example, I want to sum the number of cells (days) with a blank in the cell before it. Or, I want to sum the number of cells that are greater than the cell to the left of it.  I can't figure out how to dynamically compare to the prior column using addresses that change with each cell.

Comment: I don't know if it's because my poor English, your question is kind of unclear to me. To explain clearly, a simple screenshot is very helpful. But from what I see, you can try Excel functions like SUMIF(S) to sum, and IF to check greater or not, COUNTIF(S) can help you count. If your goal is too complicated, Macro(VBA) is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from what I understood from your Question:

If you refer to the screenshot below, you want to count Columns B to H if the column has a number and the column to the left is blank.

So, if this was just one column, we would write the formula as:

```
=COUNTIFS(B3,">0",A3,"")
```

Now since you want to do this for a range of columns (an array of cells), you need to do something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:H3,">0",A3:G3,"")
```

and accept with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
So the formula would be displayed as:

```
{=COUNTIFS(B3:H3,">0",A3:G3,"")}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  First, I apologize for my prior wording, I am actually trying to Count the cells meeting the condition, not sum them, so I want a "countif" like function.  Also, just to be clear, I only want to count cells containing a number, and for which the adjacent cell's value is blank.

Comment: So in your screenshot, Row 3 would have a count of 3, Row 6 would have a count of 2, etc.

Comment: Thanks!!  I had tried more complicated approaches and just couldn't get them to work -- I didn't realize it could be this elegant.  And your explanation of the logic was extremely helpful as I adapt it for other purposes.

Comment: @user2778881 If you this answer solved your issues, please [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) :)

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER isn't normally required for COUNTIFS function - certainly not in this case

Answer (score 0):

Array formulas are perfect for this task. I can't give you a lecture on the topic but you should read on it. Basically, you can select multiple cells in a range and act as if it was one cell.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$100="", 1, 0))
```

When you enter array formulas, be sure to hit CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER in the formula box to signify that you want Excel to treat this formula as an array formula. Otherwise you will not get the expected results.

Using this method you can do any kind of comparison. Sometimes it helps to see how Excel treats the formula. You can select part of the formula in the formula editor and hit F9 to see what this segment computes to according to Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the F9 -- very helpful!  
Please see my clarification in the other response -- I am actually trying to count those with values and the adjacent one is blank.

Comment: You can just change the return value when the condition is met. Instead of returning 1 return `$B$1:$B$100<>""` instead.